# I'm Trying to Add different items for comboBox , in the second Row

Tags: c#, .net

I need to add a different items for the same "ComboBox Text Header" comboBox 1 "Stations", and comboBox2 "Citiyes",
for the second Row [Row 2].
and different items for the three [Row=3], and so on..[Row =8].

[image]

```
        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();


                            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
                            dt.Columns.Add("Branches");
                            dt.Rows.Add("1", "Khartuom");
                            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;



            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();


            combo.HeaderText = "Stations";

            combo.Items.Add("Al mena");
            combo.Items.Add("Bahir New Station");
            combo.Items.Add("Libia");
            combo.Items.Add("PUblic shog");



            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo);

            DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
            combo2.HeaderText = "Citiyes";

            combo2.Items.Add("Port Sudan");
            combo2.Items.Add("Kasala");
            combo2.Items.Add("Madani");
            combo2.Items.Add("AlNohod");

            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(combo2);


            DataGridViewLinkColumn link = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();

            link.HeaderText = "Links page";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(link);


            DataGridViewImageColumn Image = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            Image.HeaderText = "Delete";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Image);


            DataGridViewImageColumn Image2 = new DataGridViewImageColumn();
            Image2.HeaderText = "Edit";
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add(Image2); 
}
    }
}
```

Comment: You can add the combo box columns, but as far as populating them goes, you need to use a Row level event and then bind the combo boxes with values that are relevant for that row. Look here for DataGridView Events - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.8#events

Comment: could you please write a code example ..

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. Please, edit your question and explain it a little better, not just read your code, leave a question and show us what did you try...